# Is it possible to have MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder active simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I want to have my app record a 10 second clip while playing a beep sound at certain instances (triggered by a server sending a message on a socket). The issue I am running into is that the sound does not play (even though mediaPlayer.start() is called) until the MediaRecorder has stopped.  I have also tried SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer and am running into the same issue.  I also tried moving both the recorder and player to AsyncTasks to no avail.  Any other suggestions?